# I got wrong results when I use DigestUtils.md5Hex in java

Tags: java, android

I need a way to calculate the md5 of some files to ensure the integrality in Android. 
So I use the org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex method to calcualate the md5 of a file, but I got different result as what I use `md5sum` in my linux system. 
The result of md5sum can not be wrong, so I don't know what's wrong with my code.

The code are as below(I use kotlin, but it's same as Java)):

```
val fd: AssetFileDescriptor = am.openFd("index.mp3")
var result: String = ""
val fis: FileInputStream = afd.createInputStream()
val bf: ByteArray = fis.readBytes()
val t: String = "md5sum"
result = org.apaches.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis)
```

I use both fis and bf as the paramater of md5Hex(), they have different results but not the right result.
But when I use a string like "md5sum", I got same result as other place like in Linux. 
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have an UtilsEncrypt class to get a hash with differents algorithms, but I'm using java.security instead of commons.codec.digest so my imports are:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
```

This is my code

```
    public class UtilsEncrypt {

        /**
         * @param digest 
                  encrypted message
         * 
         * @return String 
                     result in Hexadecimal format
         */
        private static String toHexadecimal(byte[] digest) {
            String hash = "";
            for (byte aux : digest) {
                int b = aux & 0xff;
                if (Integer.toHexString(b).length() == 1)
                    hash += "0";
                hash += Integer.toHexString(b);
            }
            return hash;

        }

        /***
         * Encrypt a message through an algorithm
         * 
         * @param message
         *            text to encrypt
         * @param algorithm
         *            MD2, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512
         * @return encrypted message
         */
        public static String getStringMessageDigest(String message, String algorithm) {
            byte[] digest = null;
            byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
            try {
                MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
                messageDigest.reset();
                messageDigest.update(buffer);
                digest = messageDigest.digest();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                // Do something
            }
            return toHexadecimal(digest);
        }
    }
```

As you can see I only use the fuctions that java.security gives to me. You can pass many differents algorithms to getStringMessageDigest. I have an enum with the al the types that I use. Maybe you can use another algorithms but I had no tested it with others.
Take care to reset the diggest to be sure that you have not wrong content inside and you are going to work with an 'empty' diggest.

Comment: I found what is wrong, I can't use the md5 algorithm to get the md5sum of  files in a APK. Because APK is a zipfile, the pressed processing will change the data. Whatever, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some struggle i've come to this solution, i use Okio and the code is tested compatible with Php hashing algorithm.

First extend the Java File class with an md5 function

```
import okio.HashingSource
import okio.Okio
import java.io.File

fun File.md5():String?{
    if(!this.exists())
        return null

    val hashingSource = HashingSource.md5(Okio.source(this))
    val bufferedSource = Okio.buffer(hashingSource)

    while(!bufferedSource.exhausted()){
        bufferedSource.readByteArray(1024)
    }

    return hashingSource.hash().hex()
}
```

Then you can simply generate the md5 from your file:

```
val file = File("myfile.ext");
println("File md5: ${file.md5()}")
```

Note: if the file is not found the function will return null